# .htaccess redirect domain root not sub-directories

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, cpanel

Working on a cPanel server.  I need to redirect the domain root for account to a new sub-directory but leave other sub-directories alone, many of which are used as add-on domains for other websites on the same account.

domain1.com uses
./public_html/
and needs to redirect to 
public_html/newdir

domain2.com uses
public_html/subdir

domain2.com is one of many setup this way.

Tried this but it did not work for domain2.com.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[/]?$
RewriteRule (.*) /newdir [R=301,L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried to redirect my main domain to my blog and not my sub-directory, below rule work for me.

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/exclude-directory/.*$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://redirect-to-domain.name/$1 [R=301,L]
```

!!!!